# 2 div next to each other in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to show two divs next to each other using Bootstrap, but there is a distance between them. How can i place them exactly next to each other.

The code:

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 centered">
    <div style="float: left; border: 1px solid; width: 227px; height: 50px;"></div>
    <div style="float: right; border: 1px solid;width: 227px; height: 50px;"></div>
</div>
```

Image illustration:

[image]

Comment: Why would they be beside each other? Ones float left, ones float right (each with a small width) in a container that is 8 columns wide. You are better off creating two col-lg-4 div's or adjust the div width correctly.

Comment: Why the down votes? Maybe there is a specific requirement to set the div's widths at 227px?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Look into [grids](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) in Bootstrap.

You could do something like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">div 1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">div 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice @lschlessinger, but what would happen if you don't want two columns of  `col-xs-6`? instead two `col-xs-4` and want them centered?

Comment: '<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-offset-xs-1"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
    </div>'

Comment: For those new to bootstrap, I think this needs to be within an outer <div class="container"</div> to work properly.

Answer (score 6):

Adding to Lschessinger's answer you could use offset to center the blocks. Look [***here***](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) under **Offsetting columns**

Maybe this is what you're looking for?

```
<style>
    .border {border: 1px solid #CCC;}
</style>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2 border col-xs-offset-4">div 1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 border">div 2</div>
</div>
```

Or if you have to stick to your code with the inline styles and specific widths then maybe this, you can increase the width between by increasing the width 454px to 464px for a 10px gap, and so on:

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
  <div style="width: 454px;" class="center-block">
    <div style="border: 1px solid; width: 227px; height: 50px;" class="pull-left"></div>
    <div style="border: 1px solid; width: 227px; height: 50px;" class="pull-right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to have a row containing two `div` elements. The elements will seemingly stack next to each other due to the fact that Bootstrap is built with flexbox.

In the following example I'm using the class `justify-content-center` to center both elements. And `col-auto` that will size columns based on the natural width of their content.

```css
div{border:1px solid blue}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center p-3">
    <div class="col-auto">
      content one
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto">
      content two
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Align the elements to the left by using `justify-content-start`**

```css
div{border:1px solid blue}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-start p-3">
    <div class="col-auto">
      content one
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto">
      content two
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Align the elements to the right by using `justify-content-end`**

```css
div{border:1px solid blue}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-end p-3">
    <div class="col-auto">
      content one
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto">
      content two
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** This codes do not have breakpoints. If you want to add breakpoints use this format: `col-{breakpoint}-auto` or/and `justify-content-{breakpoint}-auto`